# PC acting very weird

Tags: memory, ssd, motherboard, multi-boot, power-supply

It first appeard that my monitor would not display even though it had signal.
I was making a mkv file with my old dvd drive and I figured explorer just hanged.
Now I'm unable to get into Win10 smoothly.
Manjaro is also not smooth and hangs.
I fear my SSD is the issue but my mobo is also not smooth. Usb devices will not power at times, d0 debug appears, monitor receives no signal. 
I had also recently noticed slow write speeds to all drives. 
What could this be?

Comment: If USB devices don't get power (power, not activity), I would primarily look at the motherboard/PSU issues.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Theres no problem with the connections. Can definitely dust off parts but the system does indeed boot. The wrong CMOS setting is the only thing blocking usb devices.
It seems to be the SSD cache that is corrupt.

Comment: Cmos settings were at fault. Upon fix I did not realize uefi had to be reenabled.